# SKProductResponse invalid product identifiers. Nothing helps

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I've been searching all over the web for more than a week, i've tried everything suggested on SO and everywhere, but nothing works. I can't obtain products from Store Kit. Products array is always returned empty and invalid product identifiers is always full with my identifiers. Honestly, i have no idea what to do further. This question is my last hope. Can anybody help?

```
  NSSet *s = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"com.aceapegames.awesomecatgame.double_coins",
@"com.aceapegames.awesomecatgame.10k_coins",
@"com.aceapegames.awesomecatgame.150k_coins",
@"com.aceapegames.awesomecatgame.50k_coins",
@"com.aceapegames.awesomecatgame.disable_ads",  nil];  
SKProductsRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:s];  
request.delegate = self;
[request start];
```

Answer (score 3):

Few days Ago I have also implemented inApp purchase and I have also face this issue. In my case reason was tax information.
You need to make sure you have an iOS Paid Applications Contract setup which is located under the "Contracts, Tax, and Banking" section of iTunes connect. First you have to click on the request button, then you have to click on the 3 Set Up buttons (Contact Info, Bank Info, Tax Info)
Here is a small check list that I have copied from one website.

- Have you enabled In-App Purchases for your App ID?
- Have you checked Cleared for Sale for your product?
- Does your project’s .plist Bundle ID match your App ID?
- Have you generated and installed a new provisioning profile for the new App ID?
- Are you using the full product ID when when making an SKProductRequest?
- Are your bank details active on iTunes Connect?
- Have you tried deleting the app from your device and reinstalling?
  Make sure you can answer “**Yes**” to each of above questions

Here is a link of apple developer it contains best practicise and it's FAQ contains few more reasons of Invalid Identifier [Apple Developer Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2259/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009578-CH1-FREQUENTLY_ASKED_QUESTIONS)

Comment: i can answer YES to all the questions, but still it doesn't work

Comment: First try to find out whether there is problem in source code or account setup. Try to use with other iTunes account in which you might got working previously you or your friend.

Comment: If you can share your code then please so we can see if there is problem in code.

Comment: see the code. i don't know why it's so shifted to the right. i hope it's not a problem

Comment: Seems like issue in your account settings or something related to account. Please try to configure in other account and check. if you find any solution please update here so it may helps to others and me also :)