# i am getting nil at skproductsresponse in in app purchase which is in sandbox mode

Tags: ios5, in-app-purchase

this is for sandbox mode(testing)
i am getting null array in skproduct request

I've tried:

1. i have connected itunes with "prepare for upload" state
2. i have downloaded the provisional file and change version and bundle id which is matched to itunes connect
3. in (manage in app purchase) at itunes connect-> i had "Ready to submit"

but here

i am getting **error**:

```
    - (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response

{
    NSArray *products = response.products;

     NSLog(@"product==>%@",products);

****empty Array******

        proUpgradeProduct = [products count] == 1 ? [products objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
        if (proUpgradeProduct)
        {
            NSLog(@"Product title: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.localizedTitle);
            NSLog(@"Product description: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.localizedDescription);
            NSLog(@"Product price: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.price);
            NSLog(@"Product id: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.productIdentifier);
        }

        for (NSString *invalidProductId in response.invalidProductIdentifiers)
        {
            NSLog(@"Invalid product id: %@" , invalidProductId);
        }

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kInAppPurchaseManagerProductsFetchedNotification object:self userInfo:nil];
    }
```

Please help me....

Answer (score 0):

Check `response.invalidProductIdentifiers`. You should find your `SKProduct` in there. If so, your product identifier was not recognized by the App Store.

Comment: yes i got invalid product id only while  NSLog(@"Invalid product id: %@" , invalidProductId);

Comment: what is solution for that please tell me?

Comment: @praveen Just search for `invalidProductIdentifiers`. There're many checklists, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18511722/skproductresponse-invalid-product-identifiers-nothing-helps

Answer (score 0):

Change your bundle identifier in Project to what you have in itunes.